# Get Dummies into Rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say this is my DataFrame:

```
+-------+-----+----------------------+--------------------------+
| Month | Day | Jane                 | Bob                      |
+=======+=====+======================+==========================+
| Mar   | 10  | ['Orange', 'Apples'] | ['Banana', 'Apples']     |
+-------+-----+----------------------+--------------------------+
| Mar   | 11  | ['Pear', 'Grape']    | ['Strawberry', 'Cherry'] |
+-------+-----+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Ultimately, I want to get to this (watch for "Apple" which should appear only once in the output):

```
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Month  | Day | Fruit      | Jane | Bob |
+========+=====+============+======+=====+
| Mar    | 10  | Orange     | 1    | 0   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 10  | Apple      | 1    | 1   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 10  | Banana     | 0    | 1   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 11  | Pear       | 1    | 0   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 11  | Grape      | 1    | 0   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 11  | Strawberry | 0    | 1   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
| Mar    | 11  | Cherry     | 0    | 1   |
+--------+-----+------------+------+-----+
```

So kind of trying to do a `get_dummies` that expands into rows. Not quite sure how to tackle this. I tried starting with `explode` for each column, but in my real-life case with many more columns and values, this causes the number of rows to blow out as well, with each "Fruit" being repeated for each person (unlike the above case with "Apple").

Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried `explode`, but that's problem of cardinality, with thousands of rows being generated, I was also looking at `get_dummies`, to see if I could then flip the results with `transpose`, but then based on what can I join the results with the original table... Basically, I'm even wondering if I'm taking the problem in the right way.

Comment: Show us your code, so we can base an answer of it!

Comment: I tried `pd.get_dummies(df['Jane'].explode()).transpose().reset_index()`, but it returns one column per day (obviously), and I can't match it with the data.

Comment: If you are posting code on Stack Overflow put it into the question. Also make sure it demonstrates the problem you are having and includes all variables and input data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df["Fruit"] = df.loc[:, "Jane":].apply(
    lambda x: set(i for l in x for i in l), axis=1
)

df = df.explode("Fruit")

for c in df.loc[:, "Jane":"Bob"]:
    df[c] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x["Fruit"] in x[c]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Month  Day  Jane  Bob       Fruit
0   Mar   10     1    0      Orange
0   Mar   10     1    1      Apples
0   Mar   10     0    1      Banana
1   Mar   11     0    1      Cherry
1   Mar   11     0    1  Strawberry
1   Mar   11     1    0        Pear
1   Mar   11     1    0       Grape
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I still have to see how that works, but it does!

Answer (score 2):

We can `stack` the dataframe to reshape then `explode` the reshaped frame followed by `groupby` on `Month`, `Day` and `Fruit` then agg `level_2` with `join` and encode using `get_dummies`

```
c = ['Month', 'Day']
out = df.set_index(c).stack().explode().reset_index(name='Fruit')
out.groupby([*c, 'Fruit'], sort=False)['level_2'].agg(','.join).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

---

```
                      Bob  Jane
Month Day Fruit                
Mar   10  Orange        0     1
          Apples        1     1
          Banana        1     0
      11  Pear          0     1
          Grape         0     1
          Strawberry    1     0
          Cherry        1     0
```

---